# How do I track SignalR Connection State?

Tags: signalr

I was pointed to this [GITHub sample](https://github.com/DamianEdwards/NDCLondon2013/tree/master/UserPresence) code by David Fowler himself to track SignalR users and states. I have implemented all of it and it works great except I can't figure out the displaying of Hub connection state changes. I have this which doesn't seem to work. Does anyone know why?

```
!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style>
        #state {
            width: 20px;
            height: 50px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h3 id="msg"></h3>
    <div id="state"></div>

    <script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.0.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="signalr/hubs"></script>
    <script>

        $(function () {
            var userTracking = $.connection.alphaHub;

            // Need at least one callback for events to be raised on the hub
            userTracking.client.void = function () { };
            $.connection.logging = true;

            $.connection.hub.stateChanged(function (change) {
                if (change.newState === $.signalR.connectionState.connected) {
                    $('#state').css('background-color', 'green');
                } else if (change.newState === $.signalR.connectionState.reconnecting) {
                    $('#state').css('background-color', 'yellow');
                } else if (change.newState === $.signalR.connectionState.disconnected) {
                    $('#state').css('background-color', 'red');
                }

            });

            $.connection.hub.disconnected(function () {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $.connection.hub.start();
                }, 1000);
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

My Hub is shown partially here:

```
public class AlphaHub : Hub
    {
public override async Task OnConnected()
        {
            try
            {
                var name = Context.User.Identity.Name;

                using (savitasEntities2 entities = new savitasEntities2())
                {
                    var user = entities.SUsers
                        .Include(u => u.SConnections)
                        .SingleOrDefault(u => u.UserName == name);

                    if (user == null)
                    {
                        user = new SUser
                        {
                            UserName = name,
                            SConnections = new List<SConnection>()
                        };
                        entities.SUsers.Add(user);
                    }

                    user.SConnections.Add(new SConnection
                    {
                        ConnectionID = Context.ConnectionId,
                        UserAgent = Context.Request.Headers["User-Agent"],
                        LastActivity = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow
                    });
                    // entities.SaveChanges();
                    await entities.SaveChangesAsync();
                }

            }

 public override async Task OnDisconnected()
        {
            try
            { 
                using (savitasEntities2 db = new savitasEntities2())
                {
                    var connection = await db.SConnections.FindAsync(Context.ConnectionId);
                    db.SConnections.Remove(connection);
                    await db.SaveChangesAsync();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                c.LogError(ex.Message, "AlphaHub.cs" + " - " + this.GetType().FullName + "." + System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name);   
            }
        }
```

Comment: Do you have more info about what's not working? Any errors in the JavaScript console? Are the `OnConnected()` and `OnDisconnected()` methods being fired on the hub? Is the hub.stateChanged callback being executed?

Comment: Thanks for responding. I get SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'client' of undefined or null reference in the console, so it must not be making a connection to the Hub $.connection.alphaHub;

Comment: Do I need to add [HubName("alphaHub")] like he does with   [HubName("userTracking")]? I thought the default in JavaScript was to use the camelCase?

Comment: Check the network tab in your browser dev tools to see if the script "signalr/hubs" is loading. The locations of your other scripts makes me think it should be something like "../signalr/hubs".

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your hubs can't be found.

Change:

```
<script src="signalr/hubs"></script>
```

to:

```
<script src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>
```